# Xamarin.Forms iOS: Setting NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False" well make troubles when navigating back in iOS

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

have a look at the problem we found yesterday, 
I have two pages , Page 1 and Page2. Page1 has a button to navigate to Page2. Page two has a button that does not anything but placed for a graphical purpose . 
as I do not wish to show the navigation bar and the title on the first page "Page1" I sat the property NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar to false. That works fine and when navigating to Page2 there are no issues . The problem occurs when navigating back to "Page1" Then the button in Page2 "Does Nothing"
disappears. The problem is showen clearly when the user try to swipe back slowly as elaborated under .

---

[image: https://media.giphy.com/media/l378pMnuH7J6yQhpK/giphy.gif]

---

Comment: It works fine on my side with Visual Studio 15.3.5 and Xamarin.iOS 11. Maybe you should update vs and xamrin.ios sdk.

Comment: Have you set the "NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar" to False ?

Comment: Yes, I set it to false in my first page and set it to true in second page. And just put `<StackLayout><Button Text="Do nothing here"/></StackLayout>` in second page's `<ContentPage.Content>`. The button didn't disappear when I swipe the second page.

Comment: No make sure that the button "Do nothing here" is on the bottom of the page

Comment: I reproduce it. Controls will be move down when you pop the second page. So, the button at bottom dismiss. Actually it is moved down and out of the screen. You can file a bug here: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/

Comment: I posted a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42280419/layout-is-shifted-down-on-ios-back-gesture-if-navigation-bar-of-underneath-page
and silence there...

Comment: And there: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/88881/layout-is-shifted-down-on-ios-back-gesture-if-navigation-bar-of-underneath-page-is-hidden